# Switch object references

Tags: java, object, reference, clone

I have these two objects (`u1` and `u2`, being assigned to `Object 1` and `Object 2`, respectivly)

```
u1 = Object 1;
u2 = Object 2;
```

Now I want so switch the assignments later, so I would use this:

```
u1 = Object 2;
u2 = null;
```

I've tried this:

```
u1 = u2;
u2 = null
```

but This doesn't work because both `u1` and `u2` are assigned `null`.

How can I solve this? I can't use the clone method because I need more than a shallow copy

Comment: `u3 = u1; u1 = u2; u2 = u3;` - but what would you want to do that?

Comment: What you're doing is much _less_ than a shallow copy.

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
u1 = Object 1; 
u2 = Object 2;
Object tmp = u1;
u1 = u2;
u2 = tmp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think this wont work?

```
Object u1 = new SomeObject();
Object u2 = new SomeObject();

u1 = u2;
u2 = null;
```